# Does the size of a database affect the predictions speed of a model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, chatbot, data-analysis

I am building a chatbot model in keras, and I am planning on using it on a raspberry pi. I have a huge database with the size of (1000000, 15, 100) which means there are 1 million sample with a maximum of 15 words and the embedding dimensions are 100d using GloVe. I build a simple model consists of 1 embedding layer, 1 bidirectional lstm layer, 1 droput layer and 2 dense layer with output shape of (25,).

I know that because of the huge database the training process is going to take long, but does the size of the database going to affect the speed of model.predict or does the speed only influenced by the structure of the model and the shape of the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the size of the dataset does not affect the prediction speed of the model per se, as you say prediction computation time is only affected by the architecture of the model, and the dimensionality of the inputs.

In general the problem with making small models that are fast in embedded hardware is that as small model (with less parameters) might not perform as well as a more complex model (in terms of accuracy or error), so you have to perform a trade-off between model complexity and computational performance.